# I received Error java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, html, servlets, dao

I have a problem with my code: now i use Stringbuilder to concatening dates but i receive some errors:
My Servlet:

```
  package br.com.cad.basica;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class Contato {

        private Long id;
        private String nome;
        private String sobrenome;
        private String email;
        private String endereco;
        private Calendar dataNascimento1;
        private Calendar dataNascimento2;
        private Calendar dataNascimento3;
        private String rg;
        private String cpf;
        private String sexo;
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getNome() {
            return nome;
        }
        public void setNome(String nome) {
            this.nome = nome;
        }
        public String getSobrenome() {
            return sobrenome;
        }
        public void setSobrenome(String sobrenome) {
            this.sobrenome = sobrenome;
        }
        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }
        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
        public String getEndereco() {
            return endereco;
        }
        public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
            this.endereco = endereco;
        }
        public Calendar getDataNascimento1() {
            return dataNascimento1;
        }
        public void setDataNascimento1(Calendar dataNascimento1) {
            this.dataNascimento1 = dataNascimento1;
        }
        public Calendar getDataNascimento2() {
            return dataNascimento2;
        }
        public void setDataNascimento2(Calendar dataNascimento2) {
            this.dataNascimento2 = dataNascimento2;
        }
        public Calendar getDataNascimento3() {
            return dataNascimento3;
        }
        public void setDataNascimento3(Calendar dataNascimento3) {
            this.dataNascimento3 = dataNascimento3;
        }
        public String getRg() {
            return rg;
        }
        public void setRg(String rg) {
            this.rg = rg;
        }
        public String getCpf() {
            return cpf;
        }
        public void setCpf(String cpf) {
            this.cpf = cpf;
        }
        public String getSexo() {
            return sexo;
        }
        public void setSexo(String sexo) {
            this.sexo = sexo;
        }




}
```

My class Contato ( i dont know if need to implement some code here?)

```
  package br.com.cad.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import br.com.cad.dao.Cadastro;
import br.com.cad.basica.Contato;

public class AddDados extends HttpServlet{

    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)   
            throws IOException, ServletException { 


 PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
     String nome = request.getParameter("nome");
     String sobrenome = request.getParameter("sobrenome");
     String rg = request.getParameter("rg");  
     String cpf = request.getParameter("cpf");  
     String sexo = request.getParameter("sexo");
     StringBuilder finalDate = new StringBuilder("DataNascimento1")
.append("/"+request.getParameter("DataNascimento‌​2"))
.append("/"+request.getParameter("DataNascimento3"));

 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
 finalDate.toString(); 
 Contato contato = new Contato();  
     contato.setNome(nome); 
     contato.setSobrenome(sobrenome);
     contato.setRg(rg);  
     contato.setCpf(cpf);  
     contato.setSexo(sexo);
        if ("Masculino".equals(contato.getSexo())) {  
         contato.setSexo("M");  
            } else {  
         contato.setSexo("F");  
        }  

 Cadastro dao = new Cadastro();  
     dao.adiciona(contato);
 out.println("<html>");  
 out.println("<body>");  
 out.println("Contato " + contato.getNome() + " adicionado com sucesso");  
 out.println("</body>");  
 out.println("</html>"); 

} 
}
```

My object dao:

```
 package br.com.cad.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Date;

import br.com.cad.dao.ConnectDb;
import br.com.cad.basica.Contato;
public class Cadastro {  

    private Connection connection;  


    public Cadastro() {  
        this.connection = new ConnectDb().getConnection();  
    }  

    public void adiciona(Contato contato) {  
        String sql = "INSERT INTO dados_cadastro(pf_nome, pf_ultimonome, pf_rg, pf_cpf, pf_sexo,pf_dt_nasc) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";  
        try {  

            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);  

            stmt.setString(1, contato.getNome());  
            stmt.setString(2, contato.getSobrenome());
            stmt.setString(3, contato.getRg());  
            stmt.setString(4, contato.getCpf());
            stmt.setString(5, contato.getSexo());
            stmt.setDate(6, new Date( contato.getDataNascimento1().getTimeInMillis()) );


            stmt.execute();  
            stmt.close();  
            System.out.println("Cadastro realizado com sucesso!.");  
        } catch(SQLException sqlException) {  
            throw new RuntimeException(sqlException);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

My  htmllet code cadastra.jsp (to send data to my servlet and saving my db):

```
<...some code here
    <label>Data de nascimento</label>  
            <br>  
                <select id="birthDay" name="dataNascimento1">  
                    <option selected="" value="">Dia</option>  
                        <option value="01">1</option>  
                        <option value="02">2</option>  
</select>  
              <select id="birthMonth" name="dataNascimento2">  
                    <option selected="" value="">Mês</option>  
                        <option value="01">janeiro</option>  
                        <option value="02">fevereiro</option>  
</select>  
              <select id="birthYear" name="dataNascimento3">  
                 <option selected="" value="">Ano</option>  
                        <option value="2013">2013</option>  
                        <option value="2012">2012</option>  
</select>
```

I receive this error when pressed submit button:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
    br.com.cad.dao.Cadastro.adiciona(Cadastro.java:30)
    br.com.cad.servlet.AddDados.service(AddDados.java:48)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.40 logs.
```

Comment: The stacktrace is pretty specific: you have a `NullPointerException` in `Cadastro.adiciona` method, in the line number 30. This means, a variablee in the line 30 has a `null` value and is being used. Please **learn to read the stacktrace**.

Comment: And try to post ONLY relevant code instead of full code.

Comment: The `NullPointerException` seems to be on the line where you call `getDataNascimento1()` - are you sure this always returns a non-null value?

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `contato.setDataNascimento1(someDate)` before you add the contact(?). The problem is with this statement:

```
contato.getDataNascimento1().getTimeInMillis()
```

`contato.getDataNascimento1()` resolves to `null` at the time you execute it.

<sub>counted lines and that statement is at line 30</sub>

---

**Addition**

You should replace the lines

```
private Calendar dataNascimento1;
private Calendar dataNascimento2;
private Calendar dataNascimento3;
```

with

```
private Date dataNascimento;
```

and change the getters/setters accordingly. Now you have one field that contains the contacts birthdate and you can add it to the insert statement with no further conversion.

The only remaining challenge is how to create a `Date` object based on the captured values from the ui. A formatter is a way to do it. But `Date` has some convenient constructors to create a date based on such values. Beware, that the month is zero based, iaw, january is `0`, february `1` and so on. Once you have created the `new Date(...)` you can call the corresponding setter on the Contato class and store the birthdate on the DTO.

Comment: but my doubt is just i concatened datanascimento1+datanascimento2+datascimento3 in my stringbuilder finaldate how may add finaldate contained the 3 dates? contato.getFinalDate dont works so what i need do?

Comment: I have some more doubts. Your "Contato" class has three `Calendar` fields for the birthDate(?) and on the ui your store day, month and year in fields (as strings) with the same names. That doesn't fit in well. Design you DTO to have *one* field for the birthday and *parse* the concatenated String into a `Date`.

Comment: @Wesley - I've added some hints and suggestions to my answer.

Comment: GOOD!!! I replace my class Contato:private Date dataNascimento;public Date getDataNascimento() {
   return dataNascimento;
  }
  public void setDataNascimento(Date dataNascimento) {
   this.dataNascimento = dataNascimento;
  } but my doubt now is how may implement my servlet?StringBuilder finalDate = new StringBuilder("DataNascimento1")
.append("/"+request.getParameter("DataNascimento‌​2"))
.append("/"+request.getParameter("DataNascimento3"));
  
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
 finalDate.toString(); 
 this code i need to replace for??

Comment: User `Integer.parseInt(someString)` to convert the strings into numbers and then look at the `Date` class constructors. The last steps are really not difficult.

Comment: My servlet:  String datanascimento = request.getParameter("day"+"month"+"year"); its dont works!!!

Comment: look: String datanascimento = request.getParameter("day"+"month"+"year");
  Integer.parseInt(datanascimento);Contato contato = new Contato();  contato.setDataNascimento(datanascimento); // error here

Comment: Please have a look at the javaDoc. `int day = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("DataNascimento‌​1"));`. Last hint from my side :)

Comment: My Object dao  PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);stmt.setString(6, contato.getDataNascimento()); ???

Comment: OK how i make to concaten int day = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("DataNascimento‌​1"));int day = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("DataNascimento‌​2"));int day = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("DataNascimento‌​3")); ?